# Chrome Dev Editor Bower.json And Jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-app, bower

I am working on using Chrome Dev Editor. I am not really sure what I am doing wrong in getting jquery to be included in the bower.json. All docs I have seen talk about calling bower install from the command line or to just include in the dependencies section in the bower.json something like:

```
"jquery": "~1.8.3"
```

That has no affect that I can see (no new folder in bower_components or error messages).

If I change this to:

```
"jquery": "jquery/jquery"
```

Then I get the jquery folder in the components with the entirety of the jquery git branch. But, no jquery.min.js to actually use.

What am I doing wrong?﻿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, git clone jquery/jquery.git

[image: git cloning]

[image: git cloning2]

then drag and drop  the src folder from the newly copied repo to the `bower_components` folder of your project. then go to your `bower.json` file an in the dependencies add

```
"jquery":"jquery/jquery#master"
```

then in your project, add

```
<script src="bower_components/src/jquery.js"></script>
```

It should work!

### EDIT:

Just clone the repository, right click the repository in the File View panel (projects panel), then click click bower install.

Comment: Well, that is entirely not obvious. Is this a jqery specific thing? I have not had to do this for my other items.

Comment: @wergeld yes it should be done for all installs. drag and drop is i think better than command line `$ bower install`

Comment: I am doing this from within ChromeOS. No cmd line for this available as far as I know. When I reference higcharts it was not required to git clone. I will try this out tonight.

Comment: Me too, I have a chromebook as you can see from the screenshot. I am also familiar with windows so there is a cmd line.n make sure you see my update. make the script src `bower_components/jquery/src/jquery.js`

Comment: @wergeld which method: drag and drop or right-click bower install

Comment: I had actually spoken too soon. I used the git clone, bower install on that new jquery project. Then I added `"jquery":"jquery/jquery#master"` to bower.json and (modified yours) added to index.html `<script src="bower_components/jquery/src/jquery.js"></script>`. This loads up the jquery.js but it throws error on line 1 of it saying that `define is not defined`.